# Javascript code hiding a div doesn't work (CSS @media rule doesn't work either)- 'cannot read property style of null'

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I've got a `button` that `display` toggles a `div` on a `click` event. It works properly. However, I can't hide the same `div` using nearly the same code (however, I want to toggle this `div` after my screen becomes too big, not after clicking), because I get the problem like in the title- 'cannot read property style of null'

The part that doesn't work (hiding a `div` after screen becomes too big:

```
if (screen.width > 900) {
  document.getElementById('klik').style.display = 'none';
}
```

And the part that works (`button` toggles a `div` using a `click` `event`):

```
function showDiv() {
  if (document.getElementById('klik').style.display == 'block'){
    document.getElementById('klik').style.display = 'none';
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById('klik').style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

I wrote this code because I want to do a scalable menu, displaying a `div` with list items inside after clicking on it. The menu `button` is visible only  when `screen-width <= 900px`, if `screen-width > 900px` I've got a normal navigation bar and the `button` disappears.

Am I forgetting something? I'm new to Javascript. Also one more thing- it also doesn't work using `@media` rule, however I can change the `background-color` with `@media`. I hope it might help. Also thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the "display" property explicitly set on your element? Otherwise, it will return an empty string

Comment: How are these scripts included on the page?

Comment: are you sure your DOM is fully loaded when asking to hide something into? try `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ 
    // your code goes here
}, false);`

Comment: `cannot read property style of null` -- it sounds like `document.getElementById('klik')` doesn't exist based on the error.

Comment: @displacedtexan correct. That's the first problem. And still that code wouldn't work because he's not running it every time a window is resized - at least judging by what he has provided.

Comment: @clota974 the display is set to none in css

Comment: @MosiaThabo The problem is- it doesn't work even once. But clicking on my button changes the display from none to block and vice versa.

Comment: Please refer to my solution below? Sort the first two problems I discovered. Until then, I don't see any other problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note Two Problems:**

1. Ensure that the element you want to change it's `display` has the `id="klik"`
2. The below code will execute only once.

   `if (screen.width > 900) { document.getElementById('klik').style.display = 'none'; }`

   - But why?
     The answer is because you didn't set an `event` to run it every time when your `resize` the screen. Also, `screen.width` will always return the `width` of the display. What you are looking for is the `window.innerWidth`

**So a possible solution:**

```js
    window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
      document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = window.innerWidth.toString() + "px";
      if(window.innerWidth < 900)
      {
        //Perform your desired Executions Here
      }
    });
```

```html
<div id="screen"></div>
```

This will run the code every time a `window.onresize` is triggered. And that's exactly what `@media` in CSS does. It works on `window.onresize` behind the scene in javascript sense.

Note: I have added a simple illustration on how to work with `screen.resize` which you can use as the basis for modifying element properties based on a certain range. All you need to do, is to ensure that you do your styling within that block and it will work.

Comment: Sadly doesn't work either. Also it doesn't execute even once as u mentioned earlier.

Comment: It's not supposed to execute once. I think you're not doing it right... It must run everytime when you resize because it has to check the width and then do styling...

Comment: Share your HTMl please because it's gonna take time creating HTML again to demonstrate for you.

Comment: Mark as the answer if you're fine then. Next time when you ask you should include HTML so that it's easier to diagnose.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, actually this is exactly what media queries are made for. Did you try

```
@media (min-width: 900px) {
  #klik {
    display:  none;
  }
}
```

If that doesn't work: Are there any other css styles that may overwrite that particular style? Something like #klik { display: block !important; } ...?

Comment: Well, then some other styles may get in your way .. to find out what is happening, add media query again, expand viewport to > 900 pixels and check styles for #klik in browsers developer tools. If your media query style is applied, but overwritten by some other style, you will see your style struck through